# Using cross join with multiple variable in cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, cross-join

I have some order numbers and want to check if any number has been skipped. I'll use left table method which is:

```
select * from 
    #CreatedCrossTable (which has all possibilities)
    Left Join #MainTableWhichHaveRealSerialNo mt
where
    mt is null
```

Order no structure is: "CodeType.Year.Month.SerialNo". For instance: "DP.21.07.001","DP.21.07.002".. or not DP, but "FB.21.07.001", "FB.21.07.002" etc.

I want to create a cross table schema for determine the skipped SerilNo values (CreatedCrossTable
above):

(Serial number is reset every month)

```
CodeType | Year | Month | SerialNo
DP         21       1        1
DP         21       1        2
DP         21       1        3
DP         21       1        4
...
(All SerialNos must increase max serial number of the original table's SerialNo (MainTableWhichHaveRealSerialNo) Also codeType,year and month values must match)

DP         21       2        1
DP         21       2        2
...

FB         21       1        1
FB         21       1        2
...
FB         21       1        1
FB         21       1        2
FB         21       1        3
...
```

Each Codes' and Month's serial number have a different Maximum Number
for creating CrossTable. I've written that code:

```
;WITH cteSerialNo AS
        (
            SELECT 1 AS ORDERNO
            UNION ALL
            SELECT (ORDERNO+1) AS ORDERNO FROM cteSerialNo WHERE ORDERNO < MAX_ORDER_NO
        )
,cteMonthYear AS
        (
            SELECT CAST('2021.01.01' AS DATE) AS Dt
 
            UNION ALL

            SELECT DATEADD(MONTH , 1, Dt) AS Dt
            FROM cteMonthYear
            WHERE DATEADD (MONTH, 1, Dt) < GETDATE()
        )
SELECT
*
FROM
        (
            SELECT
                CODES.CODETYPE,
                YEAR(Dts.Dt) AS 'YEAR', 
                MONTH(Dts.Dt) AS 'MONTH'
            FROM
                ##KK_TBL_CODETYPES AS CODES
                CROSS JOIN cteMonthYear AS Dts
        ) AS CROSSTABLE
        CROSS JOIN cteSerialNo AS cSN
```

How can i enter (MAX_ORDER_NO) for each variable in this code?

Comment: You will need a lookup table of the max order number for each variable combination.  Do you have this data available? Can it be dynamically generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the max `SerialNo` value is based on the existing values in the `SerialNo` column, you would want to just find all possible combinations up to that `SerialNo` value and then remove those that have a match in the source data:

```
-- Define test data
declare @t table(CodeType varchar(2),[Year] int,[Month] int,SerialNo int);
insert into @t values
 ('DP',21,1,1)
,('DP',21,1,2)
,('DP',21,1,3)
--,('DP',21,1,4) -- Missing so should be in Output
,('DP',21,1,5)
,('DP',21,2,1)
,('DP',21,2,2)
,('FB',21,1,1)
,('FB',21,1,2)
,('FB',21,2,1)
,('FB',21,2,2)
--,('FB',21,2,3) -- Missing so should be in Output
,('FB',21,2,4)
;

with m as  -- Get Max SerialNo for each grouping
(
    select CodeType
          ,[Year]
          ,[Month]
          ,max(SerialNo) as MaxSerialNo
    from @t
    group by CodeType
            ,[Year]
            ,[Month]
)
,t as  -- Create a table with 10 rows in
(
    select t
    from(values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as t(t)
)
,n as  -- Self join those 10 rows 5 times to generate a possible 10*10*10*10*10 = 100,000 incrementing numbers using row_number
(
    select top(select max(MaxSerialNo) from m) row_number() over (order by (select null)) as n
    from t,t t2,t t3,t t4,t t5
)
-- Join from the numbers table to the source data to generate all possible SerialNo values up to the Max
select m.CodeType
      ,m.[Year]
      ,m.[Month]
      ,n.n as SerialNo
from n
    left join m
        on n.n <= m.MaxSerialNo

except -- Then exclude any that are in the source data

select CodeType
      ,[Year]
      ,[Month]
      ,SerialNo
from @t

order by CodeType
        ,[Year]
        ,[Month]
        ,SerialNo
```

### Output

| CodeType | Year | Month | SerialNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DP | 21 | 1 | 4 |
| FB | 21 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I've tried to figure out details of the code almost last one hour.   I think I got it. The complex part for me was `row_number() over (order by (select null))` I suppose it means that if the next number match null than start row number from 1 again. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: @mithderler No, it doesn't mean that at all.  It is just there to output iterative numbers.  The `order by` part is a requirement and using `(select null)` effectively means 'don't actually order anything'.  The part that limits the number to the max `SerialNo` is the `n.n <= m.MaxSerialNo` join criteria.  You can just break the statement above down to see what all the individual parts are doing if you want to understand it more